# I want to do encryption on the faces detected in a video to preserve the identity. And then perform decryption on that video to reveal faces

Tags: python, image-processing, encryption, video-processing, lossless-compression

I am working in python and this is what I have tried-

- Used the OpenCv to identify the faces and obtain coordinates of faces in the video frame.
- Passed that frame and coordinates to encryption algo (I'm using chaotic masking) to perform encryption only inside the bounding box around the faces.
- Instead of saving these coordinates in an external file so that decryption can be performed on the encrypted area, I chose to mark the boundary box surrounding the faces in frame by modifying the value of pixels on the boundary of box to (0,0,0) and perform encryption inside the box.
- Then saving the encrypted frame in a directory so that I can obtain the new video from these frames with the help of following code-

  ```
  pathIn= './frames/'
  pathOut = 'videonew.avi'
  fps = 15

  frame_array = []
  files = [f for f in os.listdir(pathIn) if isfile(join(pathIn, f))]
  #for sorting the frame names properly
  files.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[0:-4]))

  for i in range(len(files)):
      filename=pathIn + files[i]
      #reading each files
      img = cv2.imread(filename)
      height, width, layers = img.shape
      size = (width,height)

      #inserting the frames into an image array
      frame_array.append(img)
  out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), fps, size)
  for i in range(len(frame_array)):
      # writing to a image array
      out.write(frame_array[i])
  out.release()
  ```
- This works fine and created the video 'videonew.avi'. Now, to decrypt, I used following code to extract the frames from 'videonew.avi'.

  ```
  vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('videonew.avi')
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  count = 0
  path = os.getcwd() + "/test"
  os.chdir(path)
  while success:
    cv2.imwrite("%d.png" % count, image)     # save frame as PNGfile      
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    # print('Read a new frame: ', success)
    count += 1
  ```

But the extracted frames suffer some kind of compression and those (0,0,0) pixels that was marked on the boundary are not there (maybe changed). So, I can't perform decryption.
Do you know why this is happening and how can I get frames without any loss of pixel ? 
Or is there any other way to do this? I cannot store coordinates in external file because of some constraints offered by the project.

Answer (score 0):

The **avi** file format is a container format that allows for various audio and video encoding formats. Some of these formats are lossless and some of them are lossy.

Lossy formats try to compress data by partially discarding "unnecessary" data. Your (0,0,0) pixel is properbly optimized away.

You need to investigate which underlying codec (as specified to `VideoWriter_fourcc(...)` ) you should use to server your purpose. This choice is dependent of it being lossless and the support provided in your environment.